# Left align text in `\fbox`

Tags: tables

I would like text to be left-aligned in `\fbox`. I want `Student Name` and `ID` in the example below to be aligned next to the left vertical line. How can I do this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\fbox{\fbox{\parbox[b]{4.5in}{\centering

\begin{tabular}{l}

\hline\\

{\large{Student Name:}}\hspace{3in}\\[3ex]

\hline\\

 \large{ID \#}: \hspace{2.1in} 
\\[1ex]
 \hline
\end{tabular}}}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\fbox{\fbox{%
\begin{tabular}{p{4.5in}}
\hline\\
{\large{Student Name:}}\hspace{3in}\\[3ex]
\hline\\
\large{ID \#}:
\\[1ex]
 \hline
\end{tabular}}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

In your code, you are`\centering` a narrow table within a `\parbox` of `4.5in`, therefore the `tabular` is not flush left. If you draw the `\fbox`es directly around the `tabular` and specify the column as `p{4.5in}`, the tabular will be flush left.

Comment: Excellent! This is what I'm trying to do

Comment: But then the signature line is under the text,

Comment: @Sveinung you are right, but I guess I wanted it more to look like a table

Answer (score 0):

You load array, and set a second fix width column. The line you draw with a `\cline`. The vertical space between the box lines and the tabular, you can adjust with some vertical space:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\fbox{\fbox{\parbox[b]{4.5in}{\centering

\medskip

\begin{tabular}{lwl{3in}}


{\large{Student Name:}}&\\[1ex]

\cline{2-2}\\

 \large{ID \#}:& 
\\[1ex]
 \cline{2-2}
\vspace{-0.2ex}
\end{tabular}}}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want it to be aligned to the left of the box

Comment: Just a moment, I will update